# Google Script: Format URL in Array.Push

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, formatting, google-sheets

I have a working script that upon form submit, specific rows move from one sheet to another. One of the fields I'm pushing is a url.

On the second sheet, the link is listed and it is hyperlinked, but it's really ugly and I really want to format it so that it shows "Edit" with a hyperlink. I've tried a number of ways, but my knowledge is limited so all I get are errors. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Here is my code. I'm very new at this so the script is not at all sophisticated. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated!

```
function copyAdHoc(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1"));
  var data = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  // Grab the Headers from master sheet
  var headers = sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var date = headers[0].indexOf('Effective Date');
  var name = headers[0].indexOf('Employee Name');
  var loc = headers[0].indexOf('Location');
  var issue = headers[0].indexOf('Description/Question/Issue');
  var add = headers[0].indexOf('Additional Information');
  var change = headers[0].indexOf('Is this a Qualifying Life Event?');
  var url = headers[0].indexOf('Form URL');
  var category = headers[0].indexOf('Primary Category');
  var status = headers[0].indexOf('Current Status');
  var users = headers[0].indexOf('Users');

  // Grab only the relevant columns
  for(n = 0; n < data.length; ++n ) { // iterate in the array, row by row
    if (data[n][change] !== "Yes" & data[n][category] !== "Employee Relations" & data[n][date] !== "") { // if condition is true copy the whole row to target

    var arr = [];
    arr.push(data[n][url]);
    arr.push(data[n][users]);
    arr.push(data[n][date]);
    arr.push(data[n][loc]);
    arr.push(data[n][name]);
    arr.push(data[n][category]);
    arr.push(data[n][issue] + ". " + data[n][add]);
    arr.push(data[n][status]);

    var sh2 = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Ad Hoc")); //second sheet of your spreadsheet
    sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow()+1,2,1,arr.length).setValues([arr]); // paste the selected values in the 2cond sheet in one batch write

  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit messy but the only way I know to achieve what you're trying to do would be to insert a column to the left of the hyperlink with the word Edit right justified and then remove the borders between the two.

Answer (score 0):

From your description I am assuming you want the word "Edit" to be Hyperlinked. To do so, try this:

```
function getHyperlink(url)
{
  return "=HYPERLINK(\""+url+"\","+"\"Edit\""+")";
}

function mainFunct()
{
  //Do necessary steps
  var tarLink = "https://www.google.com";
  var tarRng = tarSheet.getRange(rowNum, colNum).setValue(getHyperlink(tarLink));
  //perform other steps
}
```

EDIT:
Forgot to mention, since you're pushing your values to the array... you can do it in a similar way by either just storing the hyperlink in a variable or directly pushing it to the array like all the other values. Or if you're dealing with a hyperlink that has a static and dynamic part, For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/post_id, where `post_id` keeps changing but most of the URL is static, you can easily handle it by just passing the `post_id` to the getHyperlink function and getting the required Hyperlink in return. Hope this helps.